# Android studio Firebase how to set a picture that a user selected from device storage as a user.PhotoURL

Tags: android, firebase

I have no experience in coding and i am just creating a app from tutorials in android studio. I have come a very long way in creating the app. I have implemented the code for selecting a image from the devive gallery and now i wonder how i can set that picture as a Firebase PhotoURL for the current user?

Comment: Upload it to FirebaseStorage and the callback returns a Task which contains the download URL https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented that while I was trying firebase. Hope this would do your work.

**getImageFromMobile** is set to the onClick Method of ImageButton which I am using to set Image to.

```
public void getImageFromMobile(View view) {
        if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[]{
                    android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
        }
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        intent.setType("image/");
        startActivityForResult(intent , galleryRequestCode);
    }



 private void postDataToFirebase() {
            mProgressDialog.setMessage("Posting the Blog to Firebase");
            mProgressDialog.setCancelable(false);

            final String titleValue = mPostTitle.getText().toString();
            final String description = mPostDescription.getText().toString();
            if((!TextUtils.isEmpty(titleValue))&& (!TextUtils.isEmpty(description)) && bitmap != null)
            {
                mProgressDialog.show();
                StorageReference filePath = mStorage.child("Blog_Images").child(imagePathName);
                ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 20, bytes);
                String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(PostActivity.this.getContentResolver(), bitmap, imagePathName, null);
                Uri uri = Uri.parse(path);
                filePath.putFile(uri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

                        Uri downloadUrl = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();

                        DatabaseReference newPost = mDatabaseReference.push();
                        newPost.child("Title").setValue(titleValue);
                        newPost.child("Desc").setValue(description);
                        newPost.child("imageUrl").setValue(downloadUrl.toString());
                        Toast.makeText(PostActivity.this, "Data Posted Successfully to Firebase server", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
                        Intent intent = new Intent(PostActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });

            }

        }




 @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if(requestCode == galleryRequestCode && resultCode == RESULT_OK){

            Uri imageUri = data.getData();
            imagePathName = imageUri.getLastPathSegment();
            Log.i("ImagePathName",imagePathName);
            Toast.makeText(this, "ImagePathNameto be Checked" + imagePathName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            try {
                bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), imageUri);
                imageButton.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Don't forget to set
 private int galleryRequestCode = 1;